# Smily above the text in spannable string

Tags: android, spannablestring

I used the below code to add image span.

```
Drawable happySmiley = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(
     R.drawable.img_smile);
     happySmiley.setBounds(0, 0, happySmiley.getIntrinsicWidth(),
     happySmiley.getIntrinsicHeight());

     Drawable sadSmiley = ctx.getResources()
     .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
     sadSmiley
     .setBounds(0, 0, sadSmiley.getIntrinsicWidth(),
     sadSmiley.getIntrinsicHeight());

     SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
     builder.append("Some text ");
     builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(happySmiley), builder.length()-1, builder.length(),
     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

     builder.append(". More text [sad_smiley_anchor]");
     builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(sadSmiley), builder.length()
     - "[sad_smiley_anchor]".length(), builder.length(),
     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

     tvSS.setText(builder);


o/p Some text (smiley). More text (smiley).

But I want to display the smiley above the "Some" in "Some text". Like

(Smiley)    (Smiley)
Some Text. More text.
```

If smiley can be set as background to "Some" in "Some text" like setForegroundSpan() etc. then also problem can be short out. Please comment on this.

```
Thanks
```